# Drupal Menu redirecting to dashboard of xampp

Tags: drupal-7, xampp

I have installed xampp and drupal 7 and i am trying to access my drupal website. I can see my homepage but when I redirect to any menu specified in menu it redirects to the home page of xampp. Can anyone tell what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solutions for above issue is here.

After playing around redirection it is proved that, this must be cause of  .htaccess file.
make sure that **RewriteBase** is not pointed on the root folder(**/**).
if you are not sure what it is,

find the **RewriteBase** then comment-out the line